# A connection over a 1-dim manifold is flat

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let $M$ be a 1-dimensional manifold and let $E$ be its vector bundle. I want to show that every connection $D$ on this vector bundle is flat.

A connection $D$ is flat means that we have
$$D_v D_w s-D_w D_v s -D_{[v, w]}s=0 $$
for all vector field $v, w$ and section $s$.

I am not matured in differential geometry and I don't know where to start. I don't have any idea how to use the condition that $M$ is -dimensional.

I appreciate any help.

Also, do you have any geometric intuition when you read this kind of sentence? If so, how did you learn that intuition?

Answer (score 9):

You only have one dimension for your vector fields. Write $v=a\,\partial/\partial x$ and $w=b\,\partial/\partial x$, and compute. (My personal intuition comes from thinking of curvature of a connection as a $2$-form, and the only $2$-form on a $1$-dimensional manifold is $0$. Zero curvature $\iff$ flat.)

Comment: This is true only in each fibre. Globally $v=fw$, for $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$. Given this I'm not quite sure how to show that curvature is 0.

Comment: The curvature $2$-forms live on $M$, not on $E$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Just a quick follow-up question: Given the vector fields $v$ and $w$, is the connection automatically defined? I.e. what do $D_v$ and $D_w$ look like?

Comment: @AnthonyBritto: Well, $D_{\partial/\partial x}\partial/\partial x = f(x)\,\partial/\partial x$ for some function $f$ by definition. Then you recall that $D_v = a D_{\partial/\partial x}$.

Comment: @Ted To clarify: $D_{\partial_x} = f (x) \partial_x $ by definition here only because we're in 1-D, correct?

Comment: Yes, @AnthonyBritto, although you're missing a $\partial/\partial x$ on the left. :)

Comment: @Ted: Great, thanks!